# Spring Batch and ElasticSearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

Here is my scenario..

I need to read csv file and store output to ElasticSearch. I am using Spring Batch to read csv file. can anyone give me example how to save in elasticsearch using Spring Batch or Spring Batch Extension?

Answer (score 2):

Its an old question and probably you might have found answer by now but here it goes...

To work with ElasticSearch, you need Spring Data and you simply write items from your writer as you normally do but with a repository instance like - `repository.save(list)` where `list` is a `List` of items passed from Spring Batch processor to writer.

Where `repository` is basically a [ElasticsearchRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/ElasticsearchRepository.html) from Spring Data. You need to define [repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories) for your items.

You need to provide your `ElasticsearchRepository` definitions to ElasticSearch instance definitions by editing - `@EnableElasticsearchRepositories` in and you define persistent layer as done [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.annotation). Edit `@EnableElasticsearchRepositories` to actual repository package location of your project.

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I worked with a similar project but instead of importing data from a CSV file, I imported it from a relational database MySQL, reading and filtering data with the spring batch and write it into elasticsearch , this is the link of the project in the GitHub read carefully the readme.md  file  you will find all the  required configuration :

[the github project link](https://github.com/IkbelBenAbdessamad/SpringData_Batch_Elasticsearch_Kibana.git)